# Bootstrap creating a row with 4 boxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi guys I'm using bootstrap 3 and trying to crate this effect here :

[image]

However i cant seem to create this using bootstrap at all Mine keep lying under each other, Any help on recreating this format would be great

HTML:

```
<div id="night">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6 first">
                <p>a</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 first">
                <p>a</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 first">
                <p>a</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 first">
                <p>a</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 first">
                <p>a</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.first {
        border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Create 2 columns first, then split the second into columns/rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this please

```
<div id="night">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 first">
                <div class="second">a</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 first">
                <div class="third">a</div>
                <div class="third">a</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 first">
                <div class="third">a</div>
                <div class="third">a</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.first {
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: red;
    }

    .second {
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: blue;
        display: block;
        height: 400px;
    }
    .third {
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: blue;
        display: block;
        height: 200px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in full page, maybe you can work with this aproximation:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:pink;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:blue;">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;">
          3    
        </div>    
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:green;">
          4
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:black;">
   5
 </div> 
      </div>      
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```